# Python3 flask receive file and send it to another api

Tags: python, api, file, flask, request

I am trying to receive a file in python flask endpoint via post request, and then send it to another endpoint. I receive a file on my API but I do not know how to wrap it for the next request.

The code looks like this

```
@app.route('/file', methods=['POST'])
def get_task_file():
    response_obj = {} 
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        abort(400) 

    print(request.files["file"].filename)

    # TEXT EXTRACT
    url1 = 'http://localhost:5001/text/api' 
    headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'} 

    print(type(request.files['file']))  

    r1 = requests.request("POST", url1, files={'file':request.files['file']}, headers=headers)

    print(r1.text)
```

Right now the file type is `<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'>` and I am getting 400 errors. I just want to add that the logic on the second API is similar, should I change it?

Comment: `<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'>` 
 appears to be a thin wrapper around a file like object, and not the file itself. 
 https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.html  Try `request.files['file'].read()`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. The only thing that works so far is saving the file locally and then open it with 'rb' flags. But there has to be a better way.

Comment: Found an answer that looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678673/using-flask-as-pass-through-proxy-for-file-upload

Comment: met a same issue, have u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I got code:400 as return or it shows the file I upload is empty, I found `requests` in flask is a little bit tricky.
change this

```
r1 = requests.request("POST", url1, files={'file':request.files['file']}, headers=headers)
```

into:

```
file = request.files['file']
r1 = requests.post(url1, files={'file':(file.filename, file.stream, file.content_type, file.headers)})
```